# How to declare base class that only abstract class can inherit from it?

Tags: typescript

The base class:

```
abstract class Poly extends Entity {
    kind?: string;
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.kind = this.constructor.name;
    }
}
```

Asset class can inherit from Poly :

```
abstract class Asset extends Poly {}
```

Security class can not inherit from poly:

```
class Security extends Asset {}
```

There is some options for that?

This is how i implement polymorphic:

```
abstract class Asset extends Poly {}
class Security extends Asset {}
class Bond extends Asset {}
const assets:Asset[] = [];
assets.push(new Security());
assets.push(new Bond());
assets.forEach(s => console.log(s.kind))
```

Comment: That's interesting (and I bet it can't be done). I'm curious why you want to do that...?

Comment: i wont to do what? Poly class is for implement polymorphic, so i can handle array with  security and bond, for example.

Comment: My question is: Why do you want to force `Poly` subclasses to be abstract? I can understand wanting to make a class abstract. I'm curious why you want to force its *subclasses* to be abstract.

Comment: I added the implementation for polymorphic.

Comment: So you want to disable *indirect* subclasses? But a single layer is okay?

Comment: It does not mean anything for Security to inherit from Poly

Comment: I was updating my answer because I realized it was backward, but you accepted it as I updated it. I went ahead and updated it anyway because I'm fairly sure it (now) does what you want. But if I was right the first time, let me know and I'll undo the update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a way to do it at *runtime*. I doubt it can be done at TypeScript compilation time.

My understanding is you want to disable *indirect* subclasses. So `Asset` is okay because it is a direct subclass of `Poly` (`Poly` <− `Asset`), but `Security` is not okay because it's an indirect subclass (`Poly` <− `Asset` <− `Security`).

At runtime, you could do it by checking the prototype chain and throwing from the `Poly` constructor. Here's a version that doesn't rely on any ES2015+ features (so if you have TypeScript configured to output ES5-level code, it should still work):

```
// In Poly
constructor() {
    super();
    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)) !== Poly.prototype) {
        throw new Error("Poly subclasses cannot be subclassed");
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class Entity { }

class Poly extends Entity {
    // In Poly
    constructor() {
        super();
        if (Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(this)) !== Poly.prototype) {
            throw new Error("Poly subclasses cannot be subclassed");
        }
    }
}

class Asset extends Poly {
}

class Security extends Asset {
}

// Works
try {
  new Asset();
  console.log("new Asset worked");
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}

// Fails
try {
  new Security();
  console.log("new Security worked");
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
```

Using ES2015+ features (so TypeScript would have to output an ES2015+ `class` construct, not ES5-level functions):

```
// In Poly
constructor() {
    if (new.target && Object.getPrototypeOf(new.target) !== Poly) {
        throw new Error("Poly subclasses cannot be subclassed");
    }
    super();
}
```

Live Example:

```js
class Entity { }

class Poly extends Entity {
    // In Poly
    constructor() {
        if (new.target && Object.getPrototypeOf(new.target) !== Poly) {
            throw new Error("Poly subclasses cannot be subclassed");
        }
        super();
    }
}

class Asset extends Poly {
}

class Security extends Asset {
}

// Works
try {
  new Asset();
  console.log("new Asset worked");
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}

// Fails
try {
  new Security();
  console.log("new Security worked");
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e.message);
}
```

Note that both of these can be circumvented by using `Asset`'s prototype but not its constructor (and thus, not `Poly`'s constructor). For instance, by `Object.create`.

---

In both cases if you want to change what can and can't be subclassed, you'd just change the check a bit.

Comment: Thank, i hope that it can be done in type level for prevent unnecessary runtime checks.

Comment: @yantrab - Yeah. You might want to un-accept this answer and wait a day or two in case it's possible with TypeScript and I just don't know how. Having it with no accepted answer increases the odds of people looking at it. If after a couple of days it turns out there's no TypeScript way, you can accept this answer again. Happy coding!

Comment: @yantrab - The question clearly says `Asset` should be allowed but `Security` shouldn't be. My original answer disallowed `Asset`, not `Security`. Please make sure the question is asking what you want it to ask, then ping me and I'll either roll back the update (if the question says it wants to disallow `Asset`, not `Security`) or not.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done. If one class can extend a base class there is nothing stopping someone from writing another class that extends the same base class.